# PSCP how to upload Folder in a server having password

Tags: upload, directory, using, pscp

pl help me to upload the entire folder using PSCP via command line.
i am able to download entire folder from server,but unable to upload
server has username and password
this is the below code which i am using

```
pscp -r D:\TEST\ username:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:/upload_folder
```

folder TEST contains many files as well as folders

Comment: error i am getting is "ssh_init: Host does not exist"

Comment: error i am getting is "ssh_init: Host does not exist"
if i remove password and simply use  username@xx.xx.xx.xx then it wll prompt for password. after inputting password i get error as 
"Fatal: Received unexpected end-of-file from server.."

Comment: PL help pl help